# Trying to generate Digital Signature on text By java which doe not match with final signature by C#

Tags: java, rsa, signature, digital

I want to follow some steps to generate Digital Signature using Digital Certificate(ePass2003) as follows:

1. Get encoded String
2. Generate Hash using SHA-256 algorithm
3. Generate Signature
4. Take Base64 String of that signature

---

I tried to achieve this by using java as:

1.get encoded data:

byte[] encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(data.getBytes());

2.Generate Hash using SHA-256 algorithm:

```
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] messageDigestMD5 = messageDigest.digest(encoded);
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
for (byte bytes : messageDigestMD5) {    
    stringBuffer.append(String.format("%02x", bytes & 0xff));
}
```

i am getting hash as:
0a8cc33cf59da5b9df69df8cfdcf42b795738adffc428ece54f001b8090ba0dd

3.Generate Signature
For this i tried by java Signature class and bouncy castle also:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, null);
List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
CMSTypedData cmsData= new  CMSProcessableByteArray(stringBuffer.toString().getBytes());
certList.add(certificate);
Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
CMSSignedDataGenerator cmsGenerator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
ContentSigner contentSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").build(privKey);
cmsGenerator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC") .build()).build(contentSigner, certificate.getEncoded()));
cmsGenerator.addCertificates(certs);
CMSSignedData cms = cmsGenerator.generate(cmsData, true);
```

4. Take Base64 String of that signature

```
Base64.encodeBase64String(cms.getEncoded());
```

But i am getting output as:
"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"
In C# i am using:

```
public byte[] Sign(string text, X509Certificate2 cert){
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
byte[] CryptoSignJson = csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA-256"));
return CryptoSignJson;
}
```

There output is:
'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'

Comment: I am getting confused why my both outputs are not matching? As C# output is correct help to generate same in java

Comment: Did you able to resolve this yet?  There is difference in Signature of Hash and CMS. CMS is PKCS#7 container.

Comment: @Bharat Vasant i tried in both way..means getting hash and applying cms on it or directly using cms. But still no output.

Comment: BTW, what exactly you are looking to sign here..? 'Text' is some eReturn or some file or what ?

Comment: I am looking for text(GSTN data)->Encoded(Base64)->Hash(SHA-256)->PKCS7 in the encoded format, i am following all the steps and getting output also but that output doesn't match with .net output

Comment: Are you looking to do it locally on server or want to send Hash to Web Browser where client will use his usb token to sign the hash and return PKCS7 ? If you are looking for browser solution, please refer to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55692742/9659885